# Mysql: Select after Insert failing to find rows just inserted

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

I'm not using transactions in my program, so I thought all database operations would be committed immediately.

I have a php program looking for a value in a table and return the id if it is found. If it isn't found, it writes a new row. Later on it repeats and it should find the data I just inserted, but it isn't, so I get a duplicate error.

How do I force mysql to write the data so I get a valid result back after that insert? I've tried flushing tables, but that didn't change my results.

More details:

I thought it was a generic mysql issue, but it seems to be related to using Cakephp's Model Query.

I'm using the controller to parse a CSV file into multiple tables and so bind a model on the fly and use query calls to insert data into tables as I encounter it. I'm using CakePHP for the rest of the application, but the parsing ability is kind of a throw-away functionality so I didn't spend a lot of time trying to make it elegant.

The Import model does not have an associated table, so I bind to the Tracking model manually.

Paraphrasing the code to the relevant queries:

```
    $this->Import->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Tracking')));

    $insert =<<<DONE
INSERT INTO tracking (id, created, employee_id, client_id, borrower_name, loan_number,
                  loan_amount, activity_id, program_id, rate_id, lock_period,
                  lo_price, investor_price,  committed_price, purchase_advice_price,
                  lock_type, investor_id, time_taken, notes,audited,audit_notes,
                  import_notes, import_error, uniqueness)
                  VALUES (NULL, '%s', %d,  %d,  '%s', '%s',
                          %.2f, %d, %d,  %d, %d,
                          %.5f, %.5f, %.5f, %.5f,
                          %d, %d, %d, '%s', %d, '%s',
                          '%s', %d, %d)
DONE;
while ($row = fgetscsv($fh))
    # Lots of processing deleted

    if (! $this->_exists($row))
    {
       $sql = vsprint($insert, $row);
       $this->Import->Tracking->query($sql); # This is where I'll get a duplicate error
    }
} # end of function

# I've created a unique index on columns that should be unique and I do the query on    
# them here.
private _exists($mydata)
{
       $find = "SELECT id FROM tracking WHERE created = '%s' AND employee_id = %d" AND
            activity_id = $d AND ...";
       $sql = sprintf($find, $mydata[0], $mydata[1]);
       return $this->Import->Tracking->query($sql);
}
```

So, the issue seems to be Cakephp and whatever it is doing with model queries.

I can probably yank this code out of Cake and use a stand alone php program, but since the I was already using Cakephp I figured I'd throw the import model into there.

**Additional comment:** The select is right, but I didn't transcribe it verbatim because it was long, I used ellipses to show that. It does work as I can copy/paste into a mysql session and select the data. And running it the second time, it'll find the data.

Does it sound to anyone else that Cakephp might be wrapping the entire thing into a big transaction that doesn't get committed until you exit the controller? Wouldn't that explain why the 2nd time it runs it will find those rows?

I guess I either need to figure out how to get Cakephp to commit those inserts or maybe I shouldn't be using Model->query for this and do it another way, or not use Cakephp for this part of my project.

====

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code. How can we tell without seeing it?

Comment: I suppose you are doing a select by id. Print the id and make sure you are in fact obtaining the inserted id.

Comment: We need some code please. We're just stabbing in the dark unless we know your code is right or wrong.

Comment: There's no need to "force" MySQL to write the data. A subsequent SELECT should find a row that was previously inserted. (Uncommitted transactions come into play with queries that are running from a different session, but in the same session, that's not an issue.) It's more likely an issue is in your code, than it is the database.

Comment: Well the duplicate error means that it knows the row is there. Not a caching issue. That means your select statement does not work.

Comment: Most likely your `SELECT` is wrong. What do your INSERT and SELECT statements look like?

Comment: The select works correctly. I display it and I can copy/paste it into mysql and it'll find the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CakePHP 2.5.5, just for future reference (even for myself, if I forget the solution and find my own answer in the future... hi myself!), alright, this issue is due to query cache. The fix:

`$this->Import->Tracking->query($sql, false);`

Adding the **false** param will turn off query cache. Just read the comments on the method http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Model.html#3363-3366

Comment: Ah ha! That's what I figured, it was caching somewhere. Awesome. And "hi" future Jorge. I suspect that future Panama may be back here as well!

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for LAST_INSERT_ID()

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: He's not specifically trying to find the row just inserted, he's just checking for duplicate data before another insert, and it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your $find is not a valid string:

```
   $find = "SELECT id FROM tracking WHERE created = "%s" AND employee_id = %d" AND activity_id = $d AND ...";
   //                                               ^ this is terminating the string
```

You need to wrap this in single quotes to make it the literal string. Like so:

```
   $find = 'SELECT id FROM tracking WHERE created = "%s" AND employee_id = %d" AND activity_id = $d AND ...';
```

Or escape the quotes in the string (not sure why you would do that in this case though):

```
   $find = "SELECT id FROM tracking WHERE created = \"%s\" AND employee_id = \"%d\" AND activity_id = $d AND ...";
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry but I transcribed the code incorrectly when I was yanking it from my program. The select is correct in the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on your table (and from comments in your code I see that you do) you can just use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO tracking (...)
VALUES (...)
```

That illuminates the need in doing `SELECT` prior to `INSERT`.

---

Another option to consider is to change how you are processing your CSV files to the following:

1. create a staging table with no constraints that contains all necessary columns (preferably of type `VARCHAR` ) for importing data and an auto_incremented id field
2. use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load your CSV file into the staging table in most possible efficient way
3. now you can use all SQL tools to easily clean, normalize, transform, verify against reference and factual tables your data in the staging table
4. insert data form the stagging table into factual tables
5. truncate your staging table

You can even wrap p3-5 into a stored procedure, which can further streamline your client side code.

Comment: @Panamah Did it help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was running into was something CakePHP does with the Query method. I recoded the controller so it would create associations to the models on the fly and used the built-in model save methods.

It was a more elegant solution, even if it was more coding. It also saved me from having to delve into the guts of CakePHP and figure out what the query method was doing.

Thanks for the ideas everyone!